# Mule Project scala.Option ClassNotFoundException

Tags: mule

I have getting this error when I try deploying my mule application. I've spent hours trying to resolve it but to no avail. I am using version 3.7.3 and I am not using dataweave in the project although I'm using groovy scripting. I don't have the dw: namespace either so I don't know why it's even trying to load the dataweave component

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Option
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageExtension.configureContext(WeaveExpressionLanguageExtension.scala:12) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.GlobalVariableResolverFactory.(GlobalVariableResolverFactory.java:39) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.createStaticContext(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage.initialise(MVELExpressionLanguage.java:83) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguageWrapper.initialise(MVELExpressionLanguageWrapper.java:32) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:91) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:67) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:140) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistry.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:116) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange behavior.This struck to me once. I resolved this by putting fresh copy of external dependencies once again in my repository folder.

There is similar issue reported

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Option](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-10472).

If you are using maven please check if there are corrupted files in the maven repository.Or any other dependency you are using,could get corrupted while updating mule.Check all your build libraries once or put fresh copies of external dependencies if possible(If you are using any)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. The issue had to do with dataweave pulled in by the functional-test modules.  Once I excluded the functional-test modules the problem went away.